# Getting data from closed files with concatenate formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Each day a program is creating an excel file for me with some data for the current day.
Like what is the price for products, how many people are available today and things like that.

Based on all this I need to make some forecasts and workplace allocations for workers.
The problem is, that I need to drag all this information manually all the time.
So to make it automatic I placed the formula in cells like:

```
='c:\ABC\[ABC 29-01-14.xlsx]sheet'!a1
```

Everything works fine, but next day I have to change file name for "`ABC 30-01-14`" for each cell, what is the same as entering the data manually.

So I used "`concatenate`" formula to change date according to today's date automatically.
I used "`indirect`" formula to turn it in to a real formula, not text string, and realized that it is working only for open files, not closed.

Is there any way to do this for closed files without VBA, because I don't know it, or with VBA but explained for an idiot.

Comment: You cannot pull data from a closed workbook with `indirect`, as you are aware. Either you need an absolute reference or you need a relative reference via VBA. What you describe is (unfortunately) how it's intended to work.

Comment: Oh, I found [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17837103/reference-data-in-closed-excel-sheet) that offers you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So fun fact, I have been researching this, because for a massive excel document (pulling in roughly 50 cells per week into a single document that stretches back a year and a half)

I have been able to pull the data in from closed workbooks (excel 2013 and 2016), but now in a new document I am having trouble doing so.

The way I was able to do it previously, was by creating a concatenated formula, having a macro copy that for each new month do a new row as values, then running a snippet (my thanks to the unnamed forum wizard who provided it ages past) within the macro's to remove any leading apostrophes, then dragging down the formula's for each cell.

As you have above, you do need to make sure that it is the full relative path (`'c:\abc\[abcdoc.xlsx]sheet'`).

Snippet:

```
'Removes Apostrophes from A14:AR14
    Range("A14:AI14").Select
' Removes hidden apostrophes as first character
' Works on formulas as well as text and values
    For Each CurrentCell In Selection
    If CurrentCell.HasFormula = False Then

'Checks to make sure that procedure does not
'change cell with a formula to be only the value
    CurrentCell.Formula = CurrentCell.Value
    End If
    Next
```